# Can I still play a game on Xbox Live if I move updates from HDD to memory sticks?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Xbox 360 Slim with **4 Gb HDD** and two USBs: **3.1 Gbs free** (4 Gbs total) and **4.6 Gbs free** (16 Gbs total)

Titanfall, which I have enough overall storage for its **1.5 Gbs**, says I need to store it on the HDD which is nearly full on its own.

On the HDD, Black Ops II has **2.2 Gbs** (separate files for Title Update, Vengeance map pack, something else). Curiously, BLOPS2 also has a Title Update on at least one of the other two USBs. Possibly both.

If I move the BLOPS2 files (all or just some like Vengeance since it's biggest) onto a USB stick, in either the ones with free space or a new stick, will it cause any online gameplay problems or the same problem with Titanfall prompting me to place it on the HDD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that will be fine. You may have to redownload the map packs if it doesn't recognise them.

Comment: Move them all to the same stick if you can.